# LEFT JOIN in Azure CosmosDB SQL API

Tags: azure, join, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have used JOIN in Azure Cosmos DB collection using SQL API to query documents.

I have two contact documents, one is with property Address and another one is without address.

I need to get the address list of all the persons(including the persons who is not having any address). I have used the below query to do this.
But it gives the person list who is having address.

Is there any way to do LEFT JOIN?

**Query:**

> SELECT base.FirstName, base.LastName, Address.City FROM ContactPerson
>   base  JOIN Address IN base.Address

**Sample Document:**

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Saravana",
    "LastName": "Kumar",
    "Address": [
      {
        "City": "aaaa"
      },
      {
        "City": "bbbb"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Jayanth",
    "LastName": "T"
  }
]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Saravana",
    "LastName": "Kumar",
    "City": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Saravana",
    "LastName": "Kumar",
    "City": "bbbb"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Jayanth",
    "LastName": "T"
  }
]
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Saravana",
    "LastName": "Kumar",
    "City": "bbbb"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Saravana",
    "LastName": "Kumar",
    "City": "bbbb"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know, left join is not supported by cosmos db so far,you could vote up this [thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/37949650-support-left-join).

As workaround,i suggest you using 2 different sql in stored procedure, then merge the results in it.

1.`SELECT base.FirstName, base.LastName FROM ContactPerson base where NOT IS_DEFINED(base.Address)`

2.`SELECT base.FirstName, base.LastName, Address.City FROM ContactPerson base JOIN Address IN base.Address`

SP:

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var array = [];
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT base.FirstName, base.LastName, Address.City FROM ContactPerson base JOIN Address IN base.Address',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
                array.push(feed);
        }
    });

    var isAccepted1 = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT base.FirstName, base.LastName FROM ContactPerson base where NOT IS_DEFINED(base.Address)',
    function (err, feed1, options) {
        console.log(222)
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed1|| !feed1.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {

                array.push(feed1);

        }
    });
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    response.setBody(array);

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

You could adjust the format of output as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate **LEFT JOIN** with the **EXISTS** sentence. Eg:

```
SELECT VALUE c 
FROM c
WHERE (
    --Like a "Left Join SomeCollection"
    (NOT IS_DEFINED(c.SomeCollection) OR c.SomeCollection = null)
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT null 
        FROM s IN c.SomeCollection
        WHERE s.PropertyName = 'SomeValue'
    )
)
--AND/OR Some other c Node conditions
```

Answer (score -1):

then don't join. you can directly access the Address field. ex:

```
SELECT base.FirstName, base.LastName, Address.City FROM ContactPerson base
```

it will just display null or empty string if it has no property